Passport-Discord dynamic uri
soooo basically im making this because in my code i dont want the discord auth (/auth/discord/callback) to try to redirect me to localhost:8080. Because the domain would be dynamic because this will be massdeployed and i will not have time to manually change the uri... I will give you a snippet rq:
onst CALLBACK_URL = `https://${server.address().address}:${Server.address().port}/auth/discord/callback`;

Passport.use(new DiscordStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: CALLBACK_URL,
    scope: ['identify', 'email', 'guilds'],
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    // Write user data to a text file
    fs.appendFile('users.txt', JSON.stringify(profile) + '\n', (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error writing user data to file:', err);
            return cb(err);
        }
        console.log('User data written to file:', profile);
        return cb(null, profile);
    });
  }
));

app.get('/auth/discord', Passport.authenticate('discord'));

app.get('/auth/discord/callback', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.query && req.query.code) {
        res.redirect('/apps/');
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});

I have tryed to code given to like make the thing dynamic but i want it to be smthing like
https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=('the dynamic url here)&scope=identify%20email%20guilds&client_id=1222667535900606494

What’s wrong with the code you’ve shared here? You seem to be building the URL dynamically that your requirement should be supported. However I don’t exactly see a clear problem statement, can you edit your question to articulate one? See [ask]

the problem is that when i go to (website)/auth/discord/callback it goes to discord and when I auth it redirects to localhost:8080/auth/discord/callback?idblahblahblah
instead of (websitesname)/auth/discord/callback?idblahblahblah @esqew

Ok, so how did you adjust the way your code generates the value of CALLBACK_URL to achieve the result you desire? It’s evident that server.address().address isn’t returning what you’d like it to, so why not change that? Am I missing something?

sooo i tried different options. i just rolled back code and I like. just gave up on that part.

the point is for it to be dynamic because it is a web proxy but u have to verify with discord for it to work (nummynummy data) but the problem is that there will be many links and I cant manually type them in.

I’m not quite following how any of this is or has any relation to a web proxy whatsoever. An OAuth 2 callback URL is not intended nor designed to support an infinite number of arbitrary callback URLs, and many OAuth providers require specific URLs be whitelisted so as to prevent secret leakages and other malfeasance. I think you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of what exactly this mechanism is used for in practice and I’d encourage you to research it in further detail to ensure it’s actually supporting your specific design requirements.

“i tried different options” Can you share those attempts as [mre]s with explanations as to what specifically isn’t working, per the aforementioned [ask]?

buddy the problem is that since the link is mass deployed. I don't have time to change the discord uri to something like example.com or i123.com I need the code to dynamically assign the website and a discord snippet to like figure it out so it redirects to the thing.
